# Error Undefined offset: 1 in script $a[$b] = $c

Tags: php

I am trying to resolve these errors,

> Notice: Undefined offset: 1 on line 230
>
> Notice: Undefined index: on line 231

```
$righi = file($txt);
foreach($righi as $id => $player){
    list($name, $position) = explode(">", $player);
    $weighted[$weights[trim($position)]] = trim($player);
```

Comment: please use english

Answer (score 1):

Use isset, for example:

```
if(isset($weighted[$weights[trim($position)]])){
    // your code
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but where I need to enter the function that you suggested, I am very very impractical php, be patient, thank you.

Comment: if(isset($weighted[$weights[trim($position)]])){
   $weighted[$weights[trim($position)]] = trim($player);
}